# Use non-slave vm as node in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

is it possible to define a node in jenkinsfile so that this node will use a virtual machine to run different steps in the job logic?

currently I have a jenkins job that uses **ssh agent** and a **shell script** to execute the tasks I need to take the code from the repository, run unit test, create docker images and deploy the container and it works as expected but every time I need to do a change I need to update the script instead of having all the benefits of a pipeline.

My script looks like:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null fake_user@fake_ip bash -x <<EOF
# cloning repo command
# running unit test command(s)
# creating image
# pushing image
# deploying 
EOF
```

I expect to split this commands into stages/steps in a jenkins file but executing them inside my VM

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of: if you declare a node, that means said node have been set, [one way or another](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingagents), as "agent" (new term for slave).

If not, you would not be able to reference them (like your VM) as "node" in a Jenkins pipeline.